# ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS permission granted Issue

Tags: android, permissions

Android devs.
I have a critical issue to grant the permissions.
I am developing an app to use so many permissions, but my customer doesn't like the permission dialogs for each permission. So I decrease the target SDK version to 22 to avoid the disturbing permission dialog. But I noticed a critical issue with ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS permission. I have googled and got that when the SDK version is lower than 23, there is no need to consider the permission on runtime, but just add the permission in the AndroidManifest file. But actually, when I get the return value of checkSelfPermission for ANDROID_PHONE_CALLS permission, it returns -1(denied). And some features using this permission are all failed with not permitted. Is there anyone who has experienced this, and let me know how to control this issue? Thanks! (I really hope to find the solution.) :(

Comment: You can't get around not showing permission dialogs. Since [android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#low-target-sdk-warnings) they are enforced and adjustable even in apps targetting SDK 22 or lower.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my issue is to grant the ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS permission with target SDK version 22. Is there any way?

Comment: What device (or emulator) the issue appears on? Is it android 10 (API 29) or higher?

Comment: The real devices, not emulators. I have tested with Android 9 Samsung, 10 LG.